# Как узнать раскладку клавиатуры в процессе?

Tags: c++

Пробовал таким образом:

```
HWND window = FindWindow(0,L"*Заговолок окна*");
   DWORD PID;
   GetWindowThreadProcessId(window,&PID);
   if(LOWORD(GetKeyboardLayout(PID))==0x409)
        return 1;
    return 0;
```

Но эта функция всегда возвращает 0. Почему?
Через отладчик проверял, Process ID верный.

Comment: `GetKeyboardLayout` принимает на вход идентификатор *потока* текущего процесса.

Comment: То есть нет простого способа узнать раскладку клавиатуры у другого процесса? Кроме хуков.

Comment: Наверное нет. Но мне казалось, что раскладка обычно одинаковая у всех процессов.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Может быть,потому что return 0;Но может я ошибаюсь

Comment: вопрос не о "почему", а о том, "как узнать" - и про это у вас нет ничего в ответе.